# Trying to set the tab order in Xcode for OS X App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm building an OS X Desktop app with Xcode 7.3 and I'm trying to set the tab order for one of the forms.

I've found a couple of posts explaining a similar problem for Xcode 4 but not getting anywhere with it, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRrE8eqp0dU

The basic problem i'm trying to fix is when the user is in a field and tabs I want it to tab to the field below, not the field next to it, and so on.

Looking thru the documentation it mentions wiring up the nextKeyView so it knows where to tab next to, so I've used the Interface Builder to wire up the nextKeyView for each field to point to the right one but no go.

I think I need to set the initialFirstResponder but unsure where to wire that up?

It doesn't really attach to the separate view so bit lost.

I've posted my source code here https://github.com/johnantoni/osx-tab-order

Any ideas and pointers really welcome?

At a lose end.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your project, excellent that you included it. It made playing around with AppKit easier. I am by no means an expert on AppKit, I frankly have not touched it in years but with some effort I managed to make it work.

Looks like the issues you are seeing are because of (automatic) recalculation of Key View Loop. I had to disable it with a hack, there must be a better way, but I could not find one.

```
class MyWindow: NSWindow {
    override func recalculateKeyViewLoop() {
        // Remove. nextKeyView and makeFirstResponder seemed broken with this
    }
}
```

After getting rid of the recalculation you can set the initial responder as:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    view.window?.makeFirstResponder(aField)
}
```

Tabbing now works if you have set all nextKeyViews properly in the Interface Builder.

The setup can also be done programmatically as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    aField.nextKeyView = bField
    bField.nextKeyView = cField
    cField.nextKeyView = dField
    dField.nextKeyView = aField
}
```

In code above, identifiers `aField`, `bField` etc. are outlets in the ViewController. You can add one by control dragging from the field to the view controller and naming it.

Not a perfect solution but I hope this helps.

Comment: YES!!!  Thank you Seurahepo! works brilliantly, don't think I would've found the recalculateKeyViewLoop() without your help. ace! I pushed my changes to the repo so if anyone else gets stuck they can look at it. brilliant! works like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 11 this did not work for me unless I moved the `aField.nextKeyView = bField ...` further down the view controller life cycle.  I used  `viewDidLayout` but other entry points might also work.

```
override func viewDidLayout(){
    super.viewDidLayout()
    aField.nextKeyView = bField
    bField.nextKeyView = cField
    cField.nextKeyView = dField
    dField.nextKeyView = aField
}
```